# Print Blocks of Text in R Graphics

Tags: r

Is there a way to display a plot next to text output in a single graphic using `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`?

I'm trying to display ROC curves (first plot) alongside a coefficient table (second "plot") inside a single graphic.

```
df = data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100), z = sample(0:1,100,TRUE))
fit = glm(z~x+y, data=df)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
roc(df$z, fitted(fit), plot=T, legacy.axes=T)
# This should be in the second column
print(summary(fit))
```

Also, I know this can be done with ggplot2. I'm wondering how one would do this using the built-in graphics library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make an empty plot and then use `text` to place text where you want.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(iris[,3:4], pch=20, col=rainbow(3)[iris$Species])
plot(NULL,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',bty='n',ylab='',xlab='',
    xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
text(0,0.9, pos=4,"Oh where oh where has my little dog gone?")
text(0,0.8, pos=4,"Oh where oh where can he be?")
text(0,0.7, pos=4,"with his ears cut short")
text(0,0.6, pos=4,"and his tail cut long")
text(0,0.5, pos=4,"Oh where oh where can he be?")
```

[image: Picture and text]

Answer (score 1):

With help from [G5W's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4752675/g5w) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47169814/390897), I've created a fully working code snippet. This simply captures the output as a string, and iteratively prints them into an empty plot:

```
df = data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100), z = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE))
fit = glm(z~x+y, data=df)
par(mfrow=c(1, 2), mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
roc(df$z, fitted(fit), plot=T, legacy.axes=T)
summ = capture.output(summary(fit))
plot(NULL, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', bty='n', ylab='', xlab='', xlim=c(0, 100), ylim=c(0, 100), xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i')
for (i in seq_along(summ)) {
  text(0, 100 - i*4, pos=4, summ[i], cex = 0.5, family='mono')
}
```

[image: ROC Curve with Regression Data]